# R Program for plotting Average in a Histogram

Tags: r

I am trying to write a program for plotting a barplot for average of each column. I have a data set "Dummy" containing 100 rows and 50 columns and I want to plot an average of each column and saved this barplot separately. I want averages of 50 different columns plots in a 1 barplot and saved in a certain location, how can I do it?

I am trying this syntax for plotting the average of each column of my data set, but it shows an error.

```
library(ggplot2)

for(i in 2:ncol(Dummy))
{
  jpeg(file="d:/R Data/Barplot/.jpeg")
}
barplot(colMeans(Dummy), ylim=c(0,50))
dev.off()
```

Here is the error:

```
Error in jpeg(file = "d:/R Data/Barplot/hist.jpeg") : 
too many open devices and Error in colMeans(Dummy) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: So you want to plot a histogram for each column in your dataframe? Have you tried anything in R so far?

Comment: The average of each column by this column (name) is just one value, so not a case for a histogram. Could you present an example (even just draw it) of your expected outcome?

Comment: Apparently you are confusing a histogram with a barplot. A surprisingly common mistake.

Comment: @Roland, even the barplot for the "average of each column [...] by column name" does not make sense.

Comment: @m-dz Why not? I can plot column means as a barplot (I wouldn't, but I can).

Comment: @Roland, I was not precise enough, the OP writes "and save this histogram/barplot(?) [of the average of each column] separately by column name," which will result in one bar per plot. This definitely needs to be clarified.

Comment: @m-dz Well, I have voted to close already. There is a number of close reasons that apply: unclear, too broad, no reproducible example, ...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments, that from your question, you are more likely looking for a bar plot. However, here is an example to get a histogram of column averages:

```
#Make an empty dataframe with 100 observations for 50 columns
DF<-data.frame(matrix(rep(0,50*100),nrow=100,ncol=50))

#Fill in with random values
for (i in 1:ncol(DF)){
    DF[,i]=rnorm(100,0,1)
}

#generate histogram
hist(colMeans(DF))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: why we use rnorm function here?

Comment: This was simply to create a sample database. The code you are looking for is simply the last line `hist(colMeans(DF))`, which creates a histogram of the column means of your dataframe (replace `DF` with the name of your dataframe)